# Loading PDF in WKWebView from Bundle for MacOS App through Catalyst Tool Xcode 11

Tags: swift, macos, wkwebview, xcode11, mac-catalyst

I am using WKWebView to Load PDF file from the bundle, and it works fine in iPad Device and simulator both, but when I debug that same code for Mac OS app with the help of Mac Catalyst, it just shows Blank white screen In Mac App Simulator, nothing happens.

Here is my code to load pdf from Bundle : -

```swift
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,WKNavigationDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var webKit: WKWebView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if let pdf = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "sample", withExtension: "pdf", subdirectory: nil, localization: nil)  {
           let req = NSURLRequest(url: pdf)
            webKit.load(req as URLRequest)
         }
    }
```

and it throws this error in console :-

> Could not create a 'com.apple.iphone.axserver-systemwide' sandbox extension

Even though I have configured app sandbox :-

[Have a look here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSSdL.png)

I am using
 - Xcode 11.1
 - macOS 10.15

Comment: Currently, the macOS and iOS implementations of WKWebView are different. For WKWebView, macOS Catalyst likely still uses to the macOS implemention. WWDC 2019 presentations mentions some frameworks are in common between macOS and iOS and other frameworks are not.

Answer (score 4):

WKWebView will not (currently) display PDF's using Catalyst on macOS.  Use PDFView.

Comment: Do you have a source for this? I'm wondering if it's a bug Apple might fix, or something they're just not going to support.

Comment: @arlomedia WKWebView exists in both UIKit and AppKit, and the AppKit version has never been as good. Will it be improved? Who knows. They likely didn't implement it in the first place because you should use PDFKit in AppKit.